# Updates reappear for Visual Studio 2010 dependencies

Tags: uninstall, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, asp.net

I have recently uninstalled Visual Studio 2010 C# Express from my Windows 7 x64. VS is notorious for leaving behind a bunch of dependencies and trash, and I have spent quite a bit of time manually uninstalling those dependencies and deleting the leftover files. I have a strange issue with two of them: **ASP.NET MVC 4** and **Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime**. The uninstallation proceeds normally, but when I run Windows Update, it comes up with an update for each. Installing those updates installs the programs.

I could probably just hide those updates, but Windows even finding updates seems to imply that the core programs are still installed. Of course, they are not present in the Programs list and there is no trace of them in the msiinv.exe output. Cleaning up the registry with CCleaner (which does find keys for Visual Studio afterwards) doesn't help either, nor does running that one Microsoft uninstall tool for Visual Studio that is floating around.

My concrete question: how can I make absolutely sure that these two programs are truly uninstalled? Or make Windows Update realise that they are, in fact, already gone if that's the case.